# Why my mobile application freeze while receiving data from my firebase realtime database?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

first of all, I apologize for my bad English. I'm having a lot of problems developing my mobile application in xamarin.forms. I am using the following code to receive data from my firebase realtime database but, whenever I try to request a list of users, the application freezes and does not give me an exception. Furthermore, by adding breakpoints, they do not continue parsing the code. Moreover, all the local variables of the method disappear from the debug console.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I state that this is my first experience in developing a mobile application, so don't be surprised to see gross errors or a lot of mess in the code.

```cs
//FirebaseHelper.cs

public async Task<List<Models.User>> GetUsers()
        {
            var client = new FirebaseClient(FunzioniFirebase.firebaseurl);

            var list = (await client.Child("Users").OnceAsync<Models.User>())
                .Select(item =>
                {
                    return new Models.User
                    {
                        Id = item.Key,
                        Nome = item.Object.Nome,
                        Cognome = item.Object.Cognome

                    };
                }).ToList();
            return list;
        }

public async Task<Models.User> GetUser(string id)
        {
            var client = new FirebaseClient(FunzioniFirebase.firebaseurl);
            var user = (await GetUsers()).Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return user;
        }



//User.cs


public class User
    {

        public String Id { get; set; }

        public String Nome { get; set; }

        public String Cognome { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you calling client.Dispose() there?  Unless FirebaseClient defines it differently, Dispose is meant to be called when you are through with an object and don't intend to use it again.

Comment: Excuse me, I was doing some random tests and I forgot to delete it

Comment: the code seems to right. where do you call the method ?

Comment: I declared the methods in a class "FirebaseHelper.cs" which is initialized in the body of the class "App.xaml.cs" ```c# firebase = new FirebaseHelper(); ``` .Then I call them via the "OnClicked" method of a XAML page in its c# component